# Detecting both mouse buttons held down

Tags: python, pynput

I am new to python and I found a code that detects mouse buttons when held down and released, but i want "x" to turn True when both of the buttons held down, how can I do this

```
     # This function will be called when any key of mouse is pressed
def on_click(*args):
  # see what argument is passed.
  print(args)
  if args[-1]:
    # Do something when the mouse key is pressed.
    print('The "{}" mouse key has held down'.format(args[-2].name))

elif not args[-1]:
    # Do something when the mouse key is released.
    print('The "{}" mouse key is released'.format(args[-2].name))

# Open Listener for mouse key presses
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
 # Listen to the mouse key presses
 listener.join()
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you are entirely asking but I believe you want this: 
If args[-1]: 
     x = True

Comment: your code is making x true when holding left or right, i want x to turn true when i press both right and left buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if both buttons are held down simultaneously, three variables will be required (initialise these at the start of your program, outside of the on_click function):

```
global leftPressed, rightPressed, bothPressed
leftPressed = False
rightPressed = False
bothPressed = False
```

*note the variables are global here, as multiple versions of on_click will be accessing and modifying the variables

Then, in the first if statement (when a mouse button has been pressed):

```
if args[-2].name == "left":
    leftPressed = True
elif args[-2].name == "right":
    rightPressed = True
            
if leftPressed and rightPressed:
    # if both left and right are pressed
    bothPressed = True
```

And in the second if statement (when a mouse button has been released)

```
if args[-2].name == "left":
    leftPressed = False
elif args[-2].name == "right":
    rightPressed = False

# as one key has been released, both are no longer pressed
bothPressed = False
print(bothPressed)
```

Finally, to access the global variables from within the function on_click, place this line at the start of the function:

```
global leftPressed, rightPressed, bothPressed
```

See a full version of the code here:

https://pastebin.com/nv9ddqMM